# Chart.js: Line ends in the middle of the chart - Is there a possibilty to extend the line to the edge of the chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]I've created a line chart with chart.js. Now I have the problem, that if some data is missing, the lines of the different datasets don't end at the edge of the chart. They end with their last dataset value, that isn't null.

The dataset-data is a number array and looks like: [3, 4, null, null, 120, 89, null, null, 10, 9, null, null]

Is there a possibility to extend each line to the edge of the chart?

I've attached a picture, how it currently looks like with red arrows how I want it.

I've already looked for ways to do it here on Stackoverflow, via Google and in the chart.js documentation, but haven't found anything.

Comment: How do you want to extend the line if there's no data? You could only draw a horizontal line as an annotation but you'll have a hard time matching that with the rest of the graph. The best solution seems that proposed by @gorbatkov - to add a fake data point for your fake line so it would seamlessly fit with the rest.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the rows with the last value, you can simply add them to the dataset array. Just add the elements (with the last value) between the current element index and the entire length.

By the way, you can check line API here -> https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#line-configuration

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You've understood me wrong. The last value(s) of such a dataset can be null. I don't want to add a value. I just want to extend the lines to the end of the edge of the char, which don't ends at the edge of the chart.